# Has Lego been mentioned or utilized in futuristic Sci Fi?

Tags: history-of, toys, lego

Please identify the first Sci Fi book or movie that mentions or utilizes Lego in its story line in a distant futuristic setting.

Comment: Here's a discussion about movie and TV appearances of LEGO in general: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=81925&st=325 One example from that list would be _Honey, I Shrunk the Kids (1989)_ which I'd say qualifies as sci-fi (in that movie, the kids sleep in what appears to be, at least to them, a gigantic LEGO piece) -- however, the movie is set in the present time, not the distant future.

Comment: Vote yes if you knew who asked the question before glancing at username :)

Comment: Sadly, since LEGOs weren't actually available in USSR, my usual pattern of answering with obscure yet first Soviet SFF work won't pan out here :)

Comment: does [Benny, the 1980-Something Space Guy](https://49.media.tumblr.com/d6bb77f2e20c70fbc4ee09f9b5acc4bc/tumblr_ndetefEOSU1ts8vabo1_500.gif) count?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going with Time Bandits from 1981. It features a futuristic setting (one of the characters travels forward in time to commandeer a spaceship) and is decidedly sci-fi.

In the final face off with the Ultimate Evil, the walls are made of what is  unmistakably Lego.

[image]

Comment: Could we have some context, please?

Comment: @RogueJedi - What context would you like?

Comment: Why the walls all made of giant LEGO, please.

Comment: There is the suggestion that the whole thing might be a fantasy or dream of the main character, since multiple elements of his adventures through time are foreshadowed by toys seen on his bedroom floor in an early scene, including the construction of Fortress of Ultimate Darkness resembling lego blocks, something that's never directly commented on or explained. If it isn't just a dream, perhaps the Supreme Being (who's a character in the movie) caused the kid's toys to parallel the adventures he was going to have?

Comment: @RogueJedi - What he said ↑↑↑ . At the end we find out that it was all real though...

Answer (score 4):

A candidate for one of the first depiction of legos showing up in a far-future setting (unlike Time Bandits, where the lego-like blocks appear in a Fortress of Ultimate Darkness from the "Time of Legends" which seems to be outside of normal history, though the main characters have access to time portals so they bring some weapons from future ages for a battle there) might be the story [Dramocles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42815) by Robert Sheckley, published in the March 1983 issue of Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine. I found [this excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=Id1aAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=lego) which reads:

> "What other signs of his love does Prince Chuch send me?"
>
> "My spaceship is loaded with gifts for you and your nobles," Vitello said. "There are Erector and Lego sets, puzzles and riddles, comic books, a selection of the latest rock recordings, Avon cosmetics for the ladies, and much else besides."

The excerpt itself doesn't show what story it's from, just that it's from a volume collecting the 1983 issues of Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, but looking for references to the character of "Prince Chuch" mentioned above, I found [this excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=Id1aAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22prince%20chuch%2C%20eldest%20son%22) from the same volume which refers to "Prince Chuch, eldest son of King Dramocles", so it must be from the story "Dramocles". This story was published (or expanded) as its own book later in 1983, titled [Dramocles: An Intergalactic Soap Opera](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?28275). Out of curiosity I picked up the [kindle version on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JVCHG32), it seems in this version the reference was changed to "Leggo sets", whether a typo or out of wish to avoid copyright problems. But skimming around it's clear it does take place in some distant future, for example here's an excerpt that refers to civilizations on multiple planets and the "ruins of Earth":

> The call never came, and Haldemar grew to despise the fickle superficiality of the warm-planet peoples. His deepest desire was to let loose his lapstraked spaceships upon the effete civilizations of the inner worlds. But the inner-planet peoples had too much going for them. They had deadly weapons and fast ships scavenged from the ruins of Earth, and they banded together whenever the Vanir attacked any one of them.